# Django check if a related object exists error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I have a method `has_related_object` in my model that needs to check if a related object exists

```
class Business(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

  def has_related_object(self):
        return (self.customers is not None) and (self.car is not None)


class Customer(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
      person = models.OneToOneField('Business', related_name="customer")
```

But I get the error:

> Business.has_related_object()
>
> RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Business has no customer.

Comment: I can't believe Django does not provide this method.

Comment: As shown in @mrts's answer, there is a good way to do this, `hasattr(self, 'customers')`. No need for Django to implement existing functionality.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This is because the ORM has to go to the database to check to see if `customer` exists. Since it doesn't exist, it raises an exception.

You'll have to change your method to the following:

```
def has_related_object(self):
    has_customer = False
    try:
        has_customer = (self.customers is not None)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    return has_customer and (self.car is not None)
```

I don't know the situation with `self.car` so I'll leave it to you to adjust it if it needs it.

Side note:
If you were doing this on a `Model` that has the `ForeignKeyField` or `OneToOneField` on it, you would be able to do the following as a shortcut to avoid the database query.

```
def has_business(self):
    return self.business_id is not None
```

Comment: Note that according to the doc (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#database-representation), "[...] your code should never have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object.".

Comment: This is approach is faster than the other answer, because it doesn't require talking to the database.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard, using the column name in this case is faster because Django won't try to do a join in the underlying query.  Django encourages these practices for necessary optimizations.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly

Comment: Why doesn't Django just return `None` if you try to query an object for one of its relationships? Throwing an exception seems excessive.

Comment: It's likely done to cover the case of having a nullable field. When it's allowed to be null it returns None. When it's not, then it raises an exception.

Comment: @Dan I think this (attempting `self.customers` and catching `DoesNotExist`) does make a query for customer. Django can't know if an associated customer exists without a query because the foreign key column is on customer, not business.

Answer (score 239):

Use `hasattr(self, 'customers')` to avoid the exception check as [recommended in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/):

```
def has_related_object(self):
    return hasattr(self, 'customers') and self.car is not None
```

Comment: Generally speaking in python it's EAFP.  https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: Except that asking permission is equally easy in this case, and encasing everything in try: except clauses tends to mask unrelated errors, making problems harder to debug.

Comment: @kloddant I don't think the "except" is warranted.  I think EAFP is generally *wrong* as you say, but that's not really relevant to what is the common idiom in Python. Like you (and Guido https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133118.html), I think EAFP isn't *correct*, but I do think it's the the common way writing Python.

Answer (score 10):

Although it's an old question, I thought this can be helpful for someone looking to handle this type of exception, especially when you want to check for OneToOne relations.

My solution is to use `ObjectDoesNotExist` from `django.core.exceptions`:

```py
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class Business(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def has_related_object(self):
        try:
            self.customers
            self.car
            return True
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return False


class Customer(base):
      name =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
      person = models.OneToOneField('Business', related_name="customer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably had created the user before while debuging and has no profile, so even after now coding the automation in, they still have no profile try the code below in your signal.py file, then create a superuser, log in as the super user and then add the first account's profile from there. That worked for me...

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='save_new_user_profile')
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.save()
```