# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist error inspite of using if statement

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I have the below code `if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and self.request.user. userlocation` What I don't understand is why I am getting this User has no userlocation error. I have a if statement if he condition is not met should it not just go down and show the context

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['event_list'] = Event.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and self.request.user.userlocation:
            print("The code reached here ")
        return context
```

below are the models.py

```
class UserLocation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, default='SRID=4326;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a `OneToOneField` from `UserLocation`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes it `OneToOneField` I have added the models it in the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you check my implementation of your code in the question above Am I doing something wrong I am still getting the same error

Comment: did you `import` the `ObjectDoesNotExists` error?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes `from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist` I am using pycharm professional it shows me those kind of errors

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback? It is also better to write the handling in the `else` of the `try`-`except`-`else`, since if an exception in the post-handling happens, then we do not want to catch it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem some silly mistake your code is good it worked awesome It was amazing how you figured my model even without looking at it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you constructed a model that looks similar to:

```
class UserLocation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

Contrary to popular belief, a one-to-one field does *not* mean that the referenced model (here `User`) *always* has a `UserLocation` object. A `OneToOneField` actually is a `ForeignKey` field with a `unique=True` constraint (and some extra logic such that the reverse relation is not `userlocation_set`, but `userlocation`). So it means that two `UserLocation`s can *never* refer to the *same* `User` object.

It is thus possible that there is no `user.userlocation` for some `user`, and in case the attribute is called, unfortunately it returns *not* `None`, but raises an error (there have been tickets to request that it returns `None`, but probably it will not be implemented in the (near) future, because of backwards compatibility).

So you should check with a `try`-`catch`-`except`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['event_list'] = Event.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated()
            try:
                my_location = self.request.user.userlocation
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                # ... hande case where the location does not exists
            else:
                print("The location is {}".format(my_location))
        return context
```

Comment: **`except user.userlocation.DoesNotExist:`** may a little bit more specific :)

Comment: @JPG: it is `ObjectDoesNotExists`, this is the "mother class" of all `DoesNotExists` of models. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist

Comment: By writing `user.userlocation.DoesNotExist:` the problem would *not* be resolved, since now it will raise an exception for the `user.userlocation` in the `except` clause part :)

Comment: The last comment was awesome :+1

Answer (score 7):

Use an extra condition to your ***`if`*** clause which checks for an existence of **`userlocation`** attribute by using Python's [**`hasattr()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) method

Try this

```
class Homepage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Homepage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['event_list'] = Event.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated() and \
                hasattr(self.request.user, 'userlocation') and \
                self.request.user.userlocation:
            print("The code reached here ")
        return context
```

**Reference**
[Django check if a related object exists error: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064206/django-check-if-a-related-object-exists-error-relatedobjectdoesnotexist)

Comment: This worked too thank you again for the has `hasattr()` I actually coded your solution both the solutions are awesome. I up voted your answer too. thanks for the detailed references

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem always prefer *writing descriptive answers* and I'm bit lazy ;)

Comment: and using a `try`...`catch` block is more pythonic way to handle exceptions (than conditional expressions)

Answer (score -1):

the **`User`** class doesn't have *`userlocation`* variable.
use a custom user class inherited from `User`

Comment: It that case it would have rissen an `AttributeError`. The relation is a consequence of the *reverse* of a `OneToOneField`.